# Error when trying to add orcid

Tags: formatting, arxiv

I have tried  to add orcid to Arxiv template as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\def\MakeUppercaseUnsupportedInPdfStrings{\scshape}
\usepackage{arxiv}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{academicons}
\usepackage{url}            % simple URL typesetting
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} % allow utf-8 input
\usepackage[TU]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{xcolor}% enables use of color package
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[tableposition=top]{caption} % Spaces the caption properly
\usepackage[noend]{algpseudocode}
\usepackage[linesnumbered,ruled]{algorithm2e}

    
\newcommand{\orcid}[1]{\href{https://orcid.org/#1}{\textcolor[HTML]{A6CE39}{\aiOrcid}}}

\title{AlgorithmTemplate}
\usepackage{fullpage}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}

\AtBeginDocument{%
    \providecommand\BibTeX{{%
            Bib\TeX}}}

\title{xxx}

\author{
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{orcid.pdf}\hspace{1mm}xxx}\\
    \orcid{xxx} \\
    xxx\\
    xxx\\
    xxx, xxx\\
    \texttt{xxx@xxx.xxx} \\
    \And
    {\includegraphics[scale=0.06]{orcid.pdf}\hspace{1mm}xxx} \\
    \orcid{xxx} \\
    xxx\\
    xxx\\
    xxx, xxx\\
    \texttt{xxx@xxx.xxx} \\
}


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\begin{abstract}
...
\end{abstract}
\end{document}
```

I got the following error:

[image]

**Edit**: I changed font `\usepackage[TU]{fontenc}` to `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`, but still got same errors as above.

Comment: The error is unrelated to orcid or arxiv. As it says, `\usepackage[TU]{fontenc}` is wrong, it should be `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Same issue and same errors.

Comment: You have not provided a test file  that reproduces the error, preferably just using packages in texlive (so not arxiv) try removing all the packages not used in the test document ad post the smallest _complete_ document with the error.

Comment: The main mistake you're making is trying to use pdfLaTeX to compile your document. In order to make use of the academicons package, you *must* use either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. Don't load the `fontenc`, `inputenc`, or `textcomp` packages.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. It's now a reproducible file. I just added `\end{document}` at the end.

Comment: @Mico. I did that, but I still have same issues.

Comment: Do you really need _all_  those packages to demonstrate the error? I get `! LaTeX Error: File \`arxiv.sty' not found.`  Using an up to date texlive 2022

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. I got an Arxiv template from github with `arxiv.sty`. So not sure why it's there.

Comment: but the example here should be _minimal_ Did you really need to include `booktabs` or `lipsum` remember you are asking people to trace tex behaviour: every package you add makes that harder.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. It worked. Thank you. I will share solution soon. I don't know how it worked though.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Any idea why the solution worked but the original LaTex code posted did not work please?

Comment: Please do not edit solutions in to the question. It spoils the Question and Answer format of the site. Please re-edit your question to be a quesion, and then you can self-post and accept an answer. As far as I can see you have removed the errorneous `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` which explains why you don't get that error. (I can not run your example code as I don' t have the packages used)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle. Thank you. I am not able to post an answer.

Comment: You cannot use the `academicons` package in arXiv because it requires XeTeX or LuaTeX to run. Neither of these are available in arXiv.